# Inputing an identical string multiple times to a function

Tags: python, string, list

Say I have a function, `myfunc(*iterables)`

and I want to do the following:

```
myfunc('abc','abc','abc')
```

but without repeating `'abc'` and using `n` (`=3` in the above example)

I have tried:

```
myfunc(['abc']*n)
```

However this gives

```
myfunc(['abc', 'abc', 'abc'])
```

which does not work.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [unpack the arguments list](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists), like this

```
myfunc(*['abc']*n)
```

For example,

```
def myfunc(*iterables):
    print iterables

myfunc('abc', 'abc', 'abc')   # 3 Arguments
# ('abc', 'abc', 'abc')
myfunc(['abc'] * 3)           # 1 Argument with 3 items in it
# (['abc', 'abc', 'abc'],)
myfunc(*['abc'] * 3)          # Unpack the 3 element list, to pass 3 arguments
# ('abc', 'abc', 'abc')
```

Comment: some explaination on the * ?

Comment: @alvas Just included the relevant section from the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You have the convert the list back to arguments:

```
myfunc(*['abc']*n)
```